# Difference between $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ and $f(x) = x$?

Tags: calculus, functions

So I don't seem to have understood the concept of a function.  There are three similar problems and it was on the third problem that I noticed I did not reason correctly, but I don't know why:

a) Suppose $H$ is a function and $y$ is a number such that $H(H(y)) = y$.

What is $H(H(...(H(H(y))...))$ (function beeing invoked 80 times) ?

b) Same question if $80$ invokations is replaced by $81$

c) Same question if $H(H(y)) = H(y)$

My (brief) solutions:

a) Since invoking H two times like $H(H(y)) = y$, invoking H an even number of times will equal $y$. (correct answer, although not sure about my reasoning)

b) By the same argument as in part a), invoking H an odd number of times will always result in $H(y)$. (correct answer, although not sure about my reasoning)

c) Since $H(y)$ is a number, $H(H(y)) = H(y) \iff H(n) = n$
So by induction the answer will always be equal to $y\quad $ (This is wrong, the answer is $H(y)$.

What am I doing wrong in part c)?

Comment: If $H(H(x))=H(x)$, then $H(y)=y$ for any $y$ that can be expressed as $H(x)$ for some $x$. However, for other $y$, the equation $H(y)=y$ may be false.

Comment: @PeterFranek Oh well that is a good point. I understand now, thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe an example would clarify?  The map L $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ which takes (x,y) to (x,0) clearly satisfies L(L(y)) = L(y) but it does not generally satisfy L(y) = y.

Comment: eg.  $f(x)=1$ if $x>0.5, f(x)=0$ if $x \le 0.5$ where $x \in (0,1)$ Here $f(f(0.7))=f(0.7)=1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$H(H(y))=H(y)$ says that $H(n)=n$, but only for those $n$ which are of the form $H(y)$, which might not be all numbers.

Perhaps the simplest possible example: $H(y) = 0$ for all $y$.  Then $H(H(y)) = H(y)$ for all $y$, but $H(n)=n$ is only true for $n=0$.

Answer (score 3):

For $(c)$, note that one application of $H$ to $y$ gives $H(y)$ (obviously). Two applications also yield $H(y)$, thanks to $H[H(y)]=H(y)$. Three applications yield
$$
H\{H[H(y)]\}=H\{H(y)\}=H(y).
$$
Can you continue?

Comment: Well, I understand your answer and thanks for that! @PeterFranek's comment did however, clarify why the answer could not be written as $y$ I think.

Comment: @PandaDeTapas Steven's answer and Peter's comment more directly answer your question on what you were doing wrong. So the former definitely deserves your tick mark.

Answer (score 3):

A concrete exemple of why you're wrong in c):

Take the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by $f(x) = |x|$. Then

$$f(f(x)) = |\ |x|\ | = |x| = f(x)$$

But clearly $f(x) \neq x$ (take $x$ negative)

Answer (score 2):

The correct reasoning for item c is:

Suppose that  $H(H(y)) = H(y)$.  Then $H(H(H(y)))= H(H(y)) = H(y)$. So note that $H$ applied to $y$ any number of times  will always result $H(y)$.  You can prove this last assertion using induction on the number of times $H$ is applied (not induction on the argument of $H$).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, consider $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=1$.

$f(f(x))=f(1)=1=f(x)$, but clearly $f(x)\neq x$.